# Memoir headers with small caps

Tags: header-footer, memoir, small-caps

Is there a way to set `memoir` page headers in letterspaced small caps? I didn't like the header's default style (uppercase), so I've added `\nouppercaseheads` in my preamble. This gives italic. Beautiful, but small caps would've been even better!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\renewcommand*{\memUChead}[1]{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}`. Instead of using `\textsc` and `\MakeTextLowercase`, you could also just use a smaller size macro, e.g. `\small`, to make the all caps headings smaller. This produces fake small caps, which normally are not equal to real small caps, but this could produce similar results when using a font that doesn't have real small caps.

Looking at the `memoir` class manual, you can find that `\nouppercaseheads` redefines `\memUChead` to be `\relax`, i.e. do nothing. Thus, you can redefine it yourself to do whatever you want to the header text.

Comment: I believe I have misunderstood ‘headers’. You mean page headers, I meant document division headers...

Comment: See the edits I made for my previous answer, if that is any helpful. I believe I've interpreted your question correctly now.

Comment: Yes, Erik, you've understood me right: I meant page headers. Your solution works, but the first letter in the header is still in uppercase. Is there a way to set all the text inside the header in small caps?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now it should produce lowercase small caps.

Comment: How would you also update the page numbers to be in a smaller and consistent size?

Comment: @ifly6
It's been a while since I've worked with `memoir`, so I don't know. This sounds like a question of its own that, if necessary, could refer to this question and answer.